# Money\Money could not be converted to string

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am using Money/Money with Symfony and doctrine, but I am not sure how I should perform the mapping. Currently I use the following, resulting in this error message;

**Error:**

```
Money\Money could not be converted to string
```

**Mapping:**

```
/**
 * @Groups({"group1"})
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 * @var Money
 */
private $price;
```

Internally Money/Money uses String as representation, thus I thought I could use it as well.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of doctrine type conversion. Before persisting, doctrine takes the values of your properties and transform them to SQL values using the `type` you specify in the column annotation. Since the type you are using for your price property is `string`, doctrine is trying to cast your Money object into a string.

You have many options to fix this, some of them simple and others not that much.

1. Simple but not optimal: Create a new Money class that will extend from the original one, and create `__toString` method. This will solve your problem persisting, but the property you'll get from the db will be a string, not an object. If you want to improve that, put some custom logic in your setter so you can create an instance of money from that value. Simple, but dirty.
2. Medium complex, but might not be what you need: You need to use a [doctrine custom type](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/dbal.html#registering-custom-mapping-types). Is really not that hard. People get scared of this, but jump into [the docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html) and you'll see how simple it is. It consists of basically creating a type, like "money" that contains instructions for doctrine on what to do before persisting properties of that type, and what to do after the value is fetched from the db. So you'll save it as a string in your database still, but you will also control the fetching, being able to create the Money instance. Now, depending on the structure of your money class, this might not be what you need.
3. Probably your best take: I imagine that your money class not only has the actual value, but maybe a currency type property. If that's the case, probably a [Doctrine Embeddable](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/embeddables.html) is your best solution. With that you will be able to kinda separate the actual value and the currency code as separate fields in the database. Map your money class to be a Doctrine Embeddable (since is a class that lives outside of your domain logic, in vendor, you will have to use yaml or xml, and not annotations). When the object is fetched from the db, it will be an instance of the Money class. But for that to happen, you need to have proper getters and setters that the property access component can use. Best thing about embeddables, is that they are reusable with other entities.

Hope this info helps! Happy coding!